# How can I make a cycle in the call of a process in apache camel that calls an API in the RestRoute class

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

Good afternoon, I am currently doing a development with apache camel for the first time and I am stuck at a point in which, after obtaining a list of accounts, I require for each of these accounts to call an api to retrieve information from those accounts. and I can't do it in the RestRoute class, since it's not a single call but there must be x calls depending on the account number, I can't do it and I understand in apache camel there is no for loop, yes I understand there is a loop but what What I find here is that I don't know how to go through my list to go parameter by parameter in the call from the ResRoute class

**ResRoute**

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.route;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.beans.response.UserProfile;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.exceptions.NotFoundDataException;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.exceptions.RequiredValueException;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.processor.*;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import static org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestParamType.body;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ResRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @ConfigProperty(name="client.findCustomerByDocId")
    String findCustomerByDocId;

    @ConfigProperty(name="client.findCustomerAccountListByDocId")
    String findCustomerAccountsListByDocId;

    @ConfigProperty(name="client.findPostpaidAccountInfo")
    String findPostpaidAccountInfo;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "path.openapi")
    String openApiPath;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "descripcion.servicio")
    String serviceDescription;

    private ConfigureSsl configureSsl;

    private static final String SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION = "Salida del microservicio BSS FindCustomerByDocId ${exchangeProperty[bodyRs]}";
    private static final String MSG_EXCEPTION = "Descripcion de la Exception: ${exception.message}";

    public ResRoute() {
        configureSsl = new ConfigureSsl();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
                .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .apiContextPath(openApiPath)
                .apiProperty("api.title", "FindCustomerByDocId")
                .apiProperty("api.description", serviceDescription)
                .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0.0")
                .apiProperty("cors", "true");

        rest("userProfile/v3.7/users/")
                .get("/{user_id}").to("direct:/{user_id}")
                .outType(UserProfile.class)
                .param().name("UserProfile").type(body).description("parametro de salida").required(true)
                .endParam()
                .to("direct:pipeline");

        from("direct:pipeline")
                .doTry()
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorReq())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"User ID: ${exchangeProperty[userId]}")
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Correlator ID: ${exchangeProperty[correlatorId]}")
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorReq())
                .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findCustomerByDocId))
                .choice()
                .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo(200))
                .process(new FindCustomerByDocIdProcessorRes())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Salida MS FindCustomerByDocId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerByDocIdResponse]}")
                .end()
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Document userId: ${exchangeProperty[userDocument]}")
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Name userId: ${exchangeProperty[userName]}")
                .process(new FindCustomerAccountListByDocIdReq())
                .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findCustomerAccountsListByDocId))
                .choice()
                .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isEqualTo(200))
                .process(new FindCustomerAccountsListByDocIdRes())
                /* .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Salida MS FindCustomerAccountListByDocId: ${exchangeProperty[findCustomerAccountListByDocIdResponse]}") */
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Total Cuentas Prepago: ${exchangeProperty[prepaidAccount]}")
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Total Cuentas Pospago: ${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccount]}")
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Cuentas Pospago: ${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccounts]}")
                .end()
                .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Entrada MS FindPostpaidAccountInfo: ${exchangeProperty[findPostpaidAccountInfoRequest]}")
                .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findPostpaidAccountInfo))
                .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessRes())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Salida MS FindPostpaidAccountInfo: ${exchangeProperty[findPostpaidAccountInfoResponse]}")
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorRes())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Salida MS UserProfile: ${exchangeProperty[userProfileResponse]}")
                .endDoTry()
                .doCatch(RequiredValueException.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorInvalidFormatException())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(HttpHostConnectException.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessHttpHostConectionException())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(NotFoundDataException.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorInformationSubscriber())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(UnknownHostException.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessHttpHostConectionException())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(NoHttpResponseException.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessHttpHostConectionException())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION)
                .doCatch(Exception.class)
                .process(new UserProfileProcessorException())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+MSG_EXCEPTION)
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+SALIDA_BSS_EXCEPTION);
        /*.doCatch(HttpOperationFailedException.class) */

    }

    private String getCurrentDate() {
        String timeStamp ="";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
        timeStamp= formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
        return timeStamp;
    }
}
```

Specifically where I want to make the loop is these lines:

```
            .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Total Cuentas Prepago: ${exchangeProperty[prepaidAccount]}")
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Total Cuentas Pospago: ${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccount]}")
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Cuentas Pospago: ${exchangeProperty[postpaidAccounts]}")
                .end()
                .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq())
                .log("\n["+getCurrentDate()+"]"+"Entrada MS FindPostpaidAccountInfo: ${exchangeProperty[findPostpaidAccountInfoRequest]}")
                .to(configureSsl.setupSSLContext(getCamelContext(), findPostpaidAccountInfo))
                .process(new FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessRes())
```

In the call to **FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq** I need to pass each of the following accounts that we can see in the logs and that is just on the line before the call to **FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq** through the variable **postpaidAccounts**:

[image]

The process for the API call is as follows:

```
package org.tmve.customer.ms.processor;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.tmve.customer.beans.client.findPostpaidAccountInfo.request.FindPostpaidAccountInfoInput;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.mapping.IFindPostpaidAccountInfoRequestMapping;
import org.tmve.customer.ms.mapping.impl.FindPostpaidAccountInfoRequestRequestMappingImpl;

public class FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq implements Processor {

    private IFindPostpaidAccountInfoRequestMapping findPostpaidAccountInfoRequestMapping;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public FindPostpaidAccountInfoProcessReq() {
        findPostpaidAccountInfoRequestMapping = new FindPostpaidAccountInfoRequestRequestMappingImpl();
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String accountNumber = exchange.getProperty("accountPostpaid").toString();
        String correlatorId = exchange.getProperty("correlatorId").toString();
        String userId=exchange.getProperty("userId").toString();
        FindPostpaidAccountInfoInput findPostpaidAccountInfoInput;
        findPostpaidAccountInfoInput = findPostpaidAccountInfoRequestMapping.toRequest(accountNumber,correlatorId,userId);

        String jsonFindPostpaidAccountInfoRq = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(findPostpaidAccountInfoInput);
        exchange.setProperty("findPostpaidAccountInfoRq", findPostpaidAccountInfoInput);
        exchange.setProperty("findPostpaidAccountInfoRequest", jsonFindPostpaidAccountInfoRq);
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
        exchange.getOut().setBody(jsonFindPostpaidAccountInfoRq);

    }
}
```

I am developing this in apache camel and quarkus, any ideas that could help me?